# Creating 3D plot in a new MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to create new 3d plot in new figure in MATLAB, while other figures exist. I use the `surf(...)` function, but it draws a new plot in *old* figure instead of the new figure.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It still doesn't work :<

Comment: Ok, so create a new figure `hf=figure;`, create an axis `ha=axes('Parent',hf);`, and use that axis explicitly `surf(ha,...);`.

Comment: I guess I'll make an answer then...

Comment: I turned my advice into an answer.  Feel free to accept if it helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It *should* work with `figure; surf(...)`, but if not, you can create a new figure:

```
hf = figure;
```

create an axis in that figure,

```
ha = axes('Parent',hf);
```

and then use that axis explicitly,

```
surf(ha,...);
```